# Windows generate movies in matlab which compression to use

Tags: matlab, video, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 and trying to generate movies in matlab
what compression to use?

```
movie2avi(mov, filename_mov, 'compression', 'Cinepak','quality',100);
```

Errors:

```
Use a compression method other than RLE or
MSVC for truecolor images.
The Cinepak codec is not supported in this version of Windows.
Please specify a different codec.
```

Refering:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100213-why-am-i-unable-to-use-a-compression-codec-with-avifile-using-matlab-7-7-r2008b-on-windows-xp-vist

```
movie2avi(mov, filename_mov, 'compression', 'IYUV','quality',100);
```

error:
    Error using avi
    Unexpected Error. Reason: Failed to open file.

```
Error in audiovideo.internal.aviwriter (line 168)
              aviobj.FileHandle = avi('open',filename);

Error in movie2avi (line 63)
avimov = audiovideo.internal.aviwriter(filename,varargin{:});

Error in panic_viscek_crowd (line 254)
    movie2avi(mov, filename_mov, 'compression',
    'IYUV','quality',100);

Error in gen_movies (line 9)
    gobs_all=panic_viscek_crowd(crowd_types{i},pop,tr,tloc,'movie',1);
```

Note:
I am not bound to use `.avi` only.

Comment: does it help if you use movie2avi(mov, filename_mov.avi, 'compression', 'IYUV','quality',100); -you specify filename_mov.avi?

Comment: The error is raised when opening the file, it seems to be unrelated to the compression. What filenames do you use? Maybe set a `dbstop if error` and check the contents of `filename`

Answer (score 1):

Abhishek,
movie2avi is a really old function that makes use of some old compression schemes, many of them are no longer supported on the latest versions of Windows. Use VideoWriter instead. VideoWriter allows you to write: MPEG-4/H.264, Motion JPEG AVI, Motion JPEG 2000 and a few other uncompressed formats.

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: `vidObj = VideoWriter(filename_mov);
vidObj.Quality = 100;
open(vidObj);` I am getting resolution of mere 436x344(wxh)

Comment: The resolution of the output video depends upon the size of the data you write in. VideoWriter does not change the dimensions of the image frames that you write. Can you check the size of the input you are passing to writeVideo(vidObj, data)?